# Is norm non-decreasing in each variable?

Tags: normed-spaces

Let me try again. Suppose $\|\cdot\|$ is a norm in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $$f(x_1,...,x_n)=\|(x_1,...,x_n)\|$$

where $x_i\geq 0, \forall i$. I want to prove or disprove that $f$ is an nondecreasing function in each of its variables.

Thanks

Note: Suppose we vary $x_i$ and fix the other variables. Then I want the function $g(x_i)=f((x_1,...,x_i,...,x_n))$ to be nondecreasing.

Comment: Again? Where is your previous try?

Comment: And what does "nondecreasing function in each of its variables" mean?

Comment: @ChrisEagle. im gonna edit and explain better

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, your example is wrong.

Comment: @Tomas Are you saying that $f(-1,0,0,...0)$ is not positive, or that $f(1,0,..,0)$ is not positive, or that $f(0,0,...,0)$ is not zero?

Comment: @Tomás, I don't see how Thomas Andrews' comment is wrong. This is certainly true for the $L^1$ norm. Or any $L^p$ norm, actually.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: He's failing to say that he requires every $x_i$ to be nonnegative in the question.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, im saying that $(-1,0,...,0)$ is not in the domain of definition of $f$.

Comment: @anegligibleperson, look the domain of definition of $f$

Comment: @Tomás Ok, I must have somehow missed it, or it wasn't there before my page refreshed.

Comment: Whoops, sorry @Tomás Reading comprehension error on my part.

Comment: No problem, its happens.

Comment: @Tomás Maybe you could try to change the title to something more descriptive. Something like "Is norm non-decreasing in each variable?" tells more about the question than "How to Prove that this Function in Nondecreasing?". From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.*

Comment: Thank you @MartinSleziak, i will do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We know that $\|x\|_1=|x_1|+|x_2|$ is norm on $\mathbb R^2$. (It is called $\ell_1$-norm or [taxicab norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry).) It is easy to see that [rotation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_%28mathematics%29) does not change properties of [norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28mathematics%29).

So for any angle $\varphi$ the function
$$\|x\|=|x_1\cos\varphi-x_2\sin\varphi|+|x_1\sin\varphi+x_2\cos\varphi|$$
is a norm on $\mathbb R^2$.

For $\varphi=\frac\pi 6$ we have
$$\|x\|=\frac{|\sqrt3x_1-x_2|+|x_1+\sqrt3x_2|}2.$$

If we fix $x_2=1$, then this function is not monotone in $x_1$, as we can check by plotting
[|sqrt(3)t-1|+|t+sqrt(3)|](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7Csqrt%283%29t-1%7C%2B%7Ct%2Bsqrt%283%29%7C) in WA.

Comment: Interesting @MartinSleziak. So is this question wrong: <http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/218937/proof-that-a-b-leq-c-d-if-0-leq-a-leq-c-and-0-leq-b-leq-d> ?

Comment: Well, either that or there is a mistake in my answer.

Comment: @MartinSleizak, i ploted the function and it is not nondecreasing. Maybe it is not a norm, but i think it is.

Comment: I think you answer is good, you can give this counter example there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you mean that if we hold all variables fixed, except one, then it is nondecreasing.  In that case, calculus can come to the rescue.  Take the derivative of $g$:
$$
\frac{dg}{dx_i}=\frac{d}{dx_i}\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots x_i^2+\cdots x_n^2}
$$
Since all the $x_j$ that are not equal to $x_i$ are constant, this is
$$
\frac{x_i}{\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots x_i^2+\cdots x_n^2}}
$$
If $x_i\geq 0$, then the derivative is nonnegative and $g$ is nondecreasing.

Of course, here I am assuming that you are using the standard norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: The question did not say "Euclidean norm".

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė Notice the last line of my answer.  As pointed out by Martin Sleziak, it doesn't work in general.  I was thinking the OP meant the standard norm and gave a proof for that case.

Comment: I didn't notice that line. Although I am still afraid that this answer could have been misleading to someone (were it the only answer). Though, in case you were wondering, that downvote isn't mine...

Answer (score 0):

I found this post when I had the same question. It seems to me that the answer is **no**.

Let's look at the $\ell_2$-norm: $\|\boldsymbol{x}\|_2 = \sqrt{x_1^2 + \cdots + x_n^2}$ and recall the definition of a non-decreasing function:

> A function, $f(x)$, is *non-decreasing* on an interval $I$ if $f(b) \geq f(a)$ for all $b > a$ where $a,b \in I$.

Without loss of generality, let $x_2,\ldots,x_n$ be fixed, $x_2+\cdots+x_n=C$ and write $g(x) = \sqrt{x^2 + C}$, where $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. We note that $g(-2)>g(-1)$, but $-2 \ngtr -1$. Hence, the $\ell_2$-norm is not a non-decreasing function in each of its variables.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes if $f(x)=f(|x|)$